# Unable to load properties from multiple yml file in a boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-environment

I have a microservice where I want to have few properties which are environment dependent
so I'm using application.yml, and application-dev.yml, application-int.yml etc.....

upon startup I pass `spring.profiles.active=myprofile` and relevant `applicaiton-myprofile.yml` gets loaded along with `applicaiton.yml`. So far everything works fine.

But now I want to categorize some of my non-environment-specific properties into their own business-modules, so **ALONG WITH my application.yml applicaiton-.yml** I also want to load properties from few more yml files into spring `ENVIRONMENT`. so I could be able to create create correct BusinessConfigProperties class with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

To achieve this I tried to add those yml file names in spring.config.location as below

```
     spring:
          config:
            name:
              - some-props
              - very-different-name-props
            location:
              - classpath:/config/*
```

I've provided config name too, and all my yml files are present in /config folder

But I'm still unable to read any of the properties mentioned in these file.

I can overcome this by manually loading files with `org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yml` abut that is too much boilerplate code to read YML map and instantiate my classes. There should be an easy way do achieve this with spring.

UPDATE

I updated above to,

```
     spring:
          config:
            location:
              - classpath:classpath:/config/some-props.yml,classpath:/config/very-different-name-props.yml
```

But this also isn't working
I'm not using profile, because along with above files, I already have `applicaiton-<profile>.yml` for environment specific properties. And I will be passig `spring.profile.active` as environment name in startup jvm arguments.
Also I don't want to name these files starting with application-<added_profile>.yml

Comment: That simply won't work as that is not the way to define additional properties to be loaded. Those properties need to be passed in as properties when starting the application with `--spring-config-location=`

Answer (score 0):

maybe just type in your question , it should be `spring.profiles.active=myprofile`

You can try below try approaches to load multiple files

```
spring:
  config:
    location: classpath:/config/some-props.yml,classpath:/config/some-Other-props.yml
```

---

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
      - CustomPropertiesFile
```

You can refer to this also https://youtu.be/0G9X-pTv_UU

http://roufid.com/load-multiple-configuration-files-different-directories-spring-boot/

Comment: thanks i edited `profileS` typo.  But I can not use the profile include solution.  my YML file names are not application-<CustomPropertiesFile>.yml  they are concrete names. like  payment-gateways.yml, batch-apps.yml etc (bad example) . also `spring:
  config:
    location: classpath` is also not loading properties.

Comment: try using spring.config.location in java startup command instead of main application.yml. like this java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=application,conf 
--spring.config.location=classpath:/external/properties/,classpath:/com/roufid/tutorial.

Just go through blog shared by me , you will have better clarity